# How do I insert values into this binomial heap?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, heap, binomial-heap

Binomial-Heap

[image]

1. How do I insert values like 52 into this heap?
2. What does the arrow mean?
3. How do I delete the smallest element?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like homework. Expand your question with what you have tried, and please read the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask good questions here. Thank you.

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap.